# How to change code that uses many if statements to choose a class by name?

Tags: java

I'm working on a program to simulate an RLC circuit. The program makes some specific calculations based on the type of circuit and type of source (RLC, LC, RC ,sinusoidal, DC, square ...) which later are added to Charts.

The following code works the way I need it to, but my teacher told me that it will be better if I make an individual class for every case, because too many if statements are not good.

```
if(scheme == "RLC"){
        beta = R / (2*L);
        omega0Square = 1/ (L*C);

        //Resonant
        if (omega * omega == omega0Square
                && beta >= Math.sqrt(omega0Square) / Math.sqrt(2)){

            chargeAmp = U0 / (L*2*beta*Math.sqrt(omega0Square - beta*beta));
            fi = Math.atan(Math.sqrt(omega0Square-2*beta*beta)/beta);   
        }

        //Non-resonant
        else{
            omegasDifference = (omega0Square - omega * omega);
            fi = Math.atan(2 * beta * omega / omegasDifference);
            chargeAmp = U0/(L*Math.sqrt(omegasDifference * omegasDifference
                        + 4 * beta * beta * omega * omega));
        }

        intensity = chargeAmp*omega* Math.cos(omega*time-fi);
        rU = R * intensity;
        cQ = chargeAmp*Math.sin(omega*time-fi);
        lE = L*intensity*intensity/2;
    }
    if(scheme == "LC"){

    }
    if(scheme == "RC"){

    }
    if(scheme == "R"){

    }
    if(scheme == "L"){

    }
    if(scheme == "C"){

    }
    if(scheme == "Non"){

    }
```

If I made a class for every case, how can i manage them later, and invoke them without using if statements? I thought about something like this:

```
String name;
name variable = new name();
```

Is it possible? Or is there a better way?

Comment: Before you ask your next question. Don't compare String values using `==`, use `equals()`.

Comment: i agree with ZouZou you should use equals right now its not working

Comment: (Also note that Java allows Strings to be used in `switch` statement.)

Answer (score 2):

Use Interfaces and [factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)

Create a class to hold the values ( R,L,C)

```
public class RLCHolder {
    double rValue;
    double lValue;
    double cValue;
    //Setter and Getters
}
```

Create an Interface

```
public interface CircuitCalculator {
    public double calculate(RLCHolder rlcHolder);
}
```

Now implement the Interface

```
public class RLCCircuitCalculator implements CircuitCalculator {

    @Override
    public double calculate(RLCHolder rlcHolder) {
        // Do you Math and Return
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Like this add your implementation for other Circuits like.

`LCCircuitCalculator` , `RCCircuitCalculator` and so

Now create Factory method and call the calculate method

```
public class Calculator {

    // factory method
    public static CircuitCalculator getCircuitCalculator(String circuitName){
        CircuitCalculator circuitCalculator = null;
        if (circuitName.equals("RLC")){
            circuitCalculator =  new RLCCircuitCalculator(); // You can cache if you dont maintain state
        }else if (circuitName.equals("LC")){
            // return LC object
        }//add your implementation..
        return circuitCalculator;
    }


    public static void main(String args[]){
        RLCHolder rlcHolder = new RLCHolder();
        double result = Calculator.getCircuitCalculator("RLC").calculate(rlcHolder);
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes. I was Originally planning to write using Command , but later with lazy reduced with just Interfaces. Thanks for the note. Did corrected

Answer (score 0):

Since you have different circuit i don't think you can really escape from using if statement or more elegant way you can use switch. What your teacher mean by creating seperate class for each circuit its because he want you have small chunk of code inside your if statement if you start coding like the way you code right now it will be a huge function.